# Returning a generic in java without casting it?

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have an interface like so

```
public interface ClientBuilder <Client> {

    Client build();

}
```

and it's being used in a function like this

```
private static Service createImpl(ClientBuilder clientBuilder) {
        return new serviceImpl((x) clientBuilder.build());
    }
```

Is there a way where I wouldn't have to type cast it, so that I can remove the `(x)`? It's not entirely necessary, just would be a nice to have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You make `ClientBuilder` generic in the function. And, you should follow Java naming conventions. `serviceImpl` looks like a method name (and `x` looks like a variable not a class name). But using your names, something like

```
private static Service createImpl(ClientBuilder<x> clientBuilder) {
    return new serviceImpl(clientBuilder.build());
}
```